# How to test if an object is a vector?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to test if an object is a vector, any vector, not only a vector of a single type.

I ran a test:

```
var v:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();
v.push(3);
v.push(1);
v.push(2);
trace(v is Array); // false
trace(v is Vector); // false
trace(v is Vector.<int>); // true
trace(v is Vector.<*>); // false
```

It seems that the only thing that returns true is the one which specifies the vector type, but I want to test it for ANY type.

I will need a very efficient method to compare, because `getQualifiedClassName` is too slow.

My current approach is:

```
private static function isVector(obj:Object):Boolean {
    return (getQualifiedClassName(obj).indexOf('__AS3__.vec::Vector') == 0);
}
```

But it is 2x slower than the `is` operator.

I need speed because it's for a object serialization class, and it needs to be very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other methods are way too inefficient, so I'm still using my approach:

```
private static function isVector(obj:Object):Boolean {
    return (getQualifiedClassName(obj).indexOf('__AS3__.vec::Vector') == 0);
}
```

Comment: See my answer below for a much faster solution.

Comment: @M28 I don't think you mean inefficient. I think you mean the other methods take too much code, or they look inelegant , but they are more efficient since they don't use introspection

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that Vector.<*> is a different class than that used for <Number>, <int>, or <uint>. The numeric primitives have special classes for better efficiency. String and Boolean are also primitives, but unlike the numeric primitives they are detected by <*>. As a result, you need only test for the generic Vector and the 3 numeric types.

This solution is over 2 times as fast as getQualifiedClassName in the worst case where the object is either not a Vector, or is a Vector.<uint>, and 5 times faster if the object is a non-primitive base type Vector, like Vector.<Object>:

```
return (obj is Vector.<*> 
     || obj is Vector.<Number>
     || obj is Vector.<int>
     || obj is Vector.<uint>);
```

Here's a simplistic test:

```
var moo:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();
var timer:Timer = new Timer();
var b:Boolean;
timer.startTimer();
for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    b = (moo is Vector.<*> 
      || moo is Vector.<Number> 
      || moo is Vector.<int>
      || moo is Vector.<uint>);
}
logger.info("  is timer: " + timer.endTimer());

timer.startTimer();
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    b = (flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(moo).indexOf('__AS3__.vec::Vector') == 0);
}
logger.info("gqcn timer: " + timer.endTimer());


[LOG] com.tcg.test:   is timer: 320
[LOG] com.tcg.test: gqcn timer: 756
```

Change moo to Vector.<Object>:

```
[LOG] com.tcg.test:   is timer: 158
[LOG] com.tcg.test: gqcn timer: 743
```

Comment: This is much better than the accepted answer, not even for the speed, it just makes more sense

Comment: Super agree with the above comment.

Comment: -1 this just doesn't work for * (moo = new Vector<SomeType>). Answer is wrong

Comment: @JuanMendes it just doesn't work, compared to the accepted answer

Comment: @MartinAsenov Do you have some example code? I just tested this again with Sprite instead of uint and it works fine: http://wonderfl.net/c/vfYX

Answer (score 0):

```
trace(new Array().fixed);//undefined
trace(new Object().fixed);//undefined
trace(new Vector.<Sprite>().fixed);//false
trace(new Vector.<*>().fixed);// false
```

Comment: What if it the object has a "fixed" property? I'm going to test random objects, not only arrays and vectors.

Comment: @M28 i'm afraid it will be a kind of reserved keyword

Comment: @M28 i mean you'll have to prevent anything except vectors from definition of `fixed` attribute in order to use this solution.

Comment: Well, not a good solution, I won't limit my serialization class to objects that do not contain a `fixed` variable.

Comment: @M28 let me know if you'll find a better one. and how are your objects generated?

Comment: It's a object serialization, it can be any object with any variables.

Comment: @M28 and how do you avoid as3 keywords as variable names?

Comment: @www Simple: `obj['new']`, will access the `new` variable from `obj`

Comment: @M28 btw there's another way: https://github.com/reflex/reflex-framework/blob/master/src/reflex/collections/isVector.as

Answer (score 0):

If you need serialization for any kind of object, you have to iterate over all possible types anyway, so you could use a sequential approach to find your vector type:

1. `v is ...` (simple data types)
2. `v is ...` (object types that are not collections)
3. `v is Array`
4. `v is XMLList`
5. `v is ...` (all other collection types you can think of)
6. if none of the above is true, it must be a vector
7. serialize objects in the vector.  If you have more than one type, it's `Vector.<*>`, otherwise set the vector type according to the object type of the content items.

Comment: It's waaaay slower than the method I am using

Comment: No, it isn't, not if you set up your loop efficiently.  You will have to do all those type checks anyway, don't you?  I mean, if you have to serialize any kind of object, and the data may contain any and all possible combinations - how could you get around that?  I admit that programming a loop like that will not look as neat and pretty in your code - but it will be efficient, because you don't have to use reflections at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(obj as Vector.<*>) is Vector.<*>
```

Comment: Can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32074418/edit) explain why this is an improvement over the other answers?

Comment: The `as` casting method doesn't always work, however `Boolean(Vector.<*>(obj))` does seem to. It's pretty fast with Vectors of generic types (about as fast as the `is` method) but much slower with Vectors of numeric primitives (twice as slow as the `is` method).

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// Return Class of any Target
    static public function getClass( Target:* ):Class
    {
        return getDefinitionByName ( getQualifiedClassName( Target ) ) as Class ;
    }

    /// Check if object is type of Vector.< * >
    static public function isVector( any:* ):Boolean 
    {
        return String( getClass( any ) ).indexOf( "[class Vector.<" ) > -1;
    }

    /// Get Vector < Class >
    static public function getVectorType( vector:* ):Class
    {
        var c:String = String( getClass( vector ) );
        var s:int = c.indexOf( '<' ) + 1;
        var e:int = c.indexOf( '>' );
        return getDefinitionByName( c.substring( s, e ) ) as Class;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private function getIsVector(obj:Object):Boolean
{
    return String(obj.constructor).indexOf('[class Vector.<*>]') == 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!